# Calculating scale for printing on paper

Tags: printing, scale, gis-principle

I will be making PDFs with maps on them.
Two pages, one a4, one a3 format.

Both will print the same thing, just one is going to be larger. Question - what scale do I print on the PDF? The number.
If the bounding box for the object is the same, the scales should be the same on both images, right? (here I dum out).

In example, The width of the bounding box is 6000m.
I can get that the width of a3 image printed is going to be 0.4025m (and 0.2794m for a4).

So how can I get the scale? Is it just 1:6000?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The scale is simply the absolute distance on your paper devided by the actual corresponding distance in reality. So if you paper is 29,4cm (A4) this corresponds to 6km. So your scale is 1cm --> 204m or 1m --> 20000m or **1:20000** for a landscape-format A4-document (for panel-format this would be 21cm --> 6000m or **1:28500**)

As an aside you cannot assume that on A3 the scale is simply double the amount of A4, because you have to consider the orientation of the document as well. Having said this although the actual *area* of your document is double the size the edges are not. Thus if you want to keep the orientation of your document (panel- or landscape-format) the scale changes not by the twice amount but by the following:

**Panel-Format** A3 (6000m --> 29,7cm)

```
scale(A3_panel_format) = scale(A4_panel_format) * 29,7 / 21
```

Which is about **1:20000** (notice: same as scale A4_landscape_format)

**Landscape-Format** A3 (6000m --> 42cm)

```
scale(A3_landscape_format) = scale(A4_landscape_format) * 21 / 29,7
```

Which is about **1:14000**

Comment: I had it. But I somehow thought, that the scales should be the same on both prints (given that both images represent the same thing). Confirmation was what I needed :)

Comment: This is why you need to add "when printed at Ax" after a scale when generating PDFs of maps that other people may print.

Comment: @iant, if there is no strict requirements it is handy to use scale bar instead of scale text. Scale bar will shrink/stretch accordingly to changes in print off formats, am I right?

Comment: @ChrisL that is why I always recommend the use of a scale bar for any map that leaves your hands. It doesn't matter what they do to it later the scale bar will (almost always) be right.

Comment: @iant This is not always best solution as sometimes you want to calculate with the scale. Measuring first is thus quite annoying. But maybe this is just a personal preference and opinion-based.

Comment: @HimBromBeere - how would you calculate with the scale if it is wrong because I used A4 instead of the Letter size it was designed to be printed on?

Comment: Not at all as you already mentioned. However this is not the actual problem of OP, he needs A4 and A3-scale, so I gave him the functions to get those numbers. However when dealing with numeric scales you have to assume that the paper has not been re-projected in any way (e.g. printed on letter)